# HttpWebResponse.Cookie, как правильно добавить в контейнер строку с куками?

Tags: c#

Добрый вечер.

Есть куки в виде строки, мне нужно добавить их в HttpWebResponse.Cookie, есть ли у кого пример подобного?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример [есть](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd920298(v=vs.95).aspx) у компании Макрософак

Comment: Благодарю, с ходу не нашел в MSDN.